# jQuery draggable side nav width like IDE

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

My web app has a left nav containing a tree grid. I'm hoping somebody knows of a component out there that might have similar functions to an IDE side nav. I need to be able to grab the right side of the container and expand / contract the container width dynamically. It would also need to contain a side scroll to handle overflow. Lastly it would be preferred if the nested width increases beyond the parent width do to tree expansion, the parent side scroll would auto scroll to the right.

Does anybody know of a component with similar behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at this plugin for jquery http://layout.jquery-dev.net/ . This would allow you to do most of the things you wish. The autoscrolling may not be built in (it may be as well I haven't used every feature of this plugin) but it'd be simple enough to implement. The one thing I've struggled with this plugin is efficiently styling the separator bars but other than that its a very easy to use plugin that allows resizing divs in the manner you are looking for and is great for nesting layouts etc. Also all of the scrolling of inner divs you mention is default behavior with panels in this plugin.

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I'm looking for, you saved me a ton of time and work. Thanks. I'm sure I could easily add the auto scroll if it doesn't exist.